# Emergency error of Schunk PG70

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to move a PG70 gripper together with a LWA4P using:

HW:

- Schunk LWA4P
- Schunk PG70-plus

SW:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS kinetic
- ros_canopen

I am perfectly able to move the LWA4P, but when I try to move the gripper nothing happens and after a while the gripper node has an emergency error.

This is the output of the topic `/diagnostics`:

```
level: 2
name: "rh_arm/driver: rh_arm_finger_left_joint"
message: "Motor has fault; Node has emergency error"
hardware_id: "none"
values: 
  - 
    key: "error_register"
    value: "35"
  - 
    key: "errors"
    value: "2350#df"
```

This is my terminal output:

```
    ... logging to /home/pem-robot/.ros/log/73c31b08-a3bc-11e9-ad01-2087563168c2/roslaunch-pemrobot-SIMATIC-IPC427E-1988.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://pemrobot-SIMATIC-IPC427E:38445/

SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /lh_arm/driver/
 * /mobile_base/
 * /rh_arm/driver/
 * /torso/torso_driver/

PARAMETERS
 * /joint_state_mixer/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /lh_arm/driver/bus/device: can2
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub1: 1
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub2: 24000
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/6060: 1
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_file: config/Schunk_0_6...
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_pkg: pem_arm_lh
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/vel_to_device: rint(rad2deg(vel)...
 * /lh_arm/driver/name: arm
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_0_joint/id: 10
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_1_joint/id: 5
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_2_joint/id: 6
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_3_joint/id: 3
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_4_joint/id: 4
 * /lh_arm/driver/sync/interval_ms: 50
 * /lh_arm/driver/sync/overflow: 0
 * /lh_arm/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /lh_arm/hardware_interface/joints: ['lh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /lh_arm/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /lh_arm/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/joints: ['lh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/publish_rate: 50
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/required_drive_mode: 7
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/type: position_controll...
 * /lh_arm/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/frame_id: laser_back
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/hostname: 192.168.1.20
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/max_ang: 1.0
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/min_ang: -1.0
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/port: 2112
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/range_max: 25.0
 * /mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back/timelimit: 5
 * /mobile_base/driver/bus/device: can0
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1016sub0: 0x1
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1016sub1: 0x007f00c8
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1017: 0x0032
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1400sub2: 0x1
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1600sub0: 0x2
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1600sub1: 0x60400010
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1600sub2: 0x60ff0020
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1800sub2: 0x1
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1801sub2: 0x1
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1a00sub0: 0x1
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1a00sub1: 0x60410010
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1a01sub0: 0x2
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1a01sub1: 0x606c0020
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/1a01sub2: 0x60640020
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/eds_file: config/CANeds-Gol...
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/eds_pkg: pem_robot_mobile_...
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/pos_from_device: obj6064*2*3.14/60...
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/pos_to_device: rint(pos*50.0*60....
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/vel_from_device: obj606C*2.0*3.14/...
 * /mobile_base/driver/defaults/vel_to_device: rint(vel*50.0*60....
 * /mobile_base/driver/heartbeat/msg: 77f#05
 * /mobile_base/driver/heartbeat/rate: 20
 * /mobile_base/driver/name: motor
 * /mobile_base/driver/nodes/left_wheel_joint/id: 1
 * /mobile_base/driver/nodes/right_wheel_joint/id: 2
 * /mobile_base/driver/sync/interval_ms: 10
 * /mobile_base/driver/sync/overflow: 0
 * /mobile_base/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /mobile_base/hardware_interface/joints: ['left_wheel_join...
 * /mobile_base/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /mobile_base/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/has_jerk_limits: False
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/max_acceleration: 1.0
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/max_jerk: 1.0
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/max_velocity: 1.3
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/min_acceleration: -1.0
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/angular/z/min_velocity: -1.3
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/base_frame_id: base_footprint
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.05
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/left_wheel: left_wheel_joint
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/has_jerk_limits: False
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/max_acceleration: 0.5
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/max_jerk: 0.05
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/max_velocity: 0.57
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/min_acceleration: -0.5
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/linear/x/min_velocity: -0.57
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.0001, 0.0001, ...
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/publish_cmd: True
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/required_drive_mode: 3
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/right_wheel: right_wheel_joint
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.0001, 0.0001, ...
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/type: diff_drive_contro...
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/wheel_radius: 0.076
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/wheel_separation: 0.75
 * /mobile_base/mobile_base_controller/wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
 * /rh_arm/driver/bus/device: can3
 * /rh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_file: config/Schunk_0_6...
 * /rh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_pkg: pem_arm_rh
 * /rh_arm/driver/name: arm
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_0_joint/id: 10
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_1_joint/id: 5
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_2_joint/id: 6
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_3_joint/id: 3
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_4_joint/id: 4
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_5_joint/id: 7
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_6_joint/id: 8
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_finger_left_joint/id: 12
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_finger_left_joint/pos_from_device: obj6064/2000000.0
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_finger_left_joint/pos_to_device: pos*2000000.0
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_finger_left_joint/vel_from_device: obj606C/2000000.0
 * /rh_arm/driver/nodes/rh_arm_finger_left_joint/vel_to_device: vel*2000000.0
 * /rh_arm/driver/sync/interval_ms: 50
 * /rh_arm/driver/sync/overflow: 0
 * /rh_arm/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /rh_arm/hardware_interface/joints: ['rh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /rh_arm/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /rh_arm/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /rh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh/joints: ['rh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /rh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh/publish_rate: 50
 * /rh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh/required_drive_mode: 7
 * /rh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh/type: position_controll...
 * /rh_arm/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /sick_tim571_front/frame_id: laser_front
 * /sick_tim571_front/hostname: 192.168.1.10
 * /sick_tim571_front/port: 2112
 * /sick_tim571_front/range_max: 25.0
 * /sick_tim571_front/timelimit: 5
 * /torso/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /torso/hardware_interface/joints: ['torso_1_joint',...
 * /torso/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /torso/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /torso/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso/joints: ['torso_1_joint',...
 * /torso/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso/publish_rate: 50
 * /torso/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso/required_drive_mode: 7
 * /torso/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso/type: position_controll...
 * /torso/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /torso/torso_driver/bus/device: can1
 * /torso/torso_driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub1: 1
 * /torso/torso_driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub2: 24000
 * /torso/torso_driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/6060: 1
 * /torso/torso_driver/defaults/eds_file: config/Schunk_0_6...
 * /torso/torso_driver/defaults/eds_pkg: pem_torso
 * /torso/torso_driver/defaults/vel_to_device: rint(rad2deg(vel)...
 * /torso/torso_driver/name: arm
 * /torso/torso_driver/nodes/torso_1_joint/id: 1
 * /torso/torso_driver/nodes/torso_2_joint/id: 2
 * /torso/torso_driver/sync/interval_ms: 50
 * /torso/torso_driver/sync/overflow: 0

NODES
  /lh_arm/
    driver (canopen_motor_node/canopen_motor_node)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
  /
    joint_state_mixer (pem_robot/joint_state_mixer.py)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    sick_tim571_front (sick_tim/sick_tim551_2050001)
  /mobile_base/back/
    sick_tim571_back (sick_tim/sick_tim551_2050001)
  /torso/
    initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    robot_initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    torso_driver (canopen_motor_node/canopen_motor_node)
    torso_joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
  /mobile_base/
    driver (canopen_motor_node/canopen_motor_node)
    initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    wheel_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
  /rh_arm/
    driver (canopen_motor_node/canopen_motor_node)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2129]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 73c31b08-a3bc-11e9-ad01-2087563168c2
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2186]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rh_arm/driver-2]: started with pid [2304]
process[rh_arm/ros_control_controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [2310]
process[rh_arm/joint_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [2324]
process[rh_arm/robot_initialization-5]: started with pid [2329]
process[lh_arm/driver-6]: started with pid [2336]
process[lh_arm/ros_control_controller_spawner-7]: started with pid [2353]
process[lh_arm/joint_state_publisher-8]: started with pid [2354]
process[lh_arm/robot_initialization-9]: started with pid [2362]
process[torso/torso_driver-10]: started with pid [2373]
process[torso/ros_control_controller_spawner-11]: started with pid [2374]
process[torso/torso_joint_state_publisher-12]: started with pid [2375]
process[torso/initialization-13]: started with pid [2376]
process[torso/robot_initialization-14]: started with pid [2377]
process[mobile_base/wheel_controller_spawner-15]: started with pid [2383]
process[mobile_base/driver-16]: started with pid [2402]
process[mobile_base/initialization-17]: started with pid [2403]
process[mobile_base/back/sick_tim571_back-18]: started with pid [2404]
process[sick_tim571_front-19]: started with pid [2409]
process[joint_state_mixer-20]: started with pid [2431]
process[robot_state_publisher-21]: started with pid [2445]
[INFO] [1562836545.859613]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1562836545.905646668]: Initializing XXX
[INFO] [1562836545.933354]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1562836545.945579274]: Waiting 5 seconds for device to connect.
[ INFO] [1562836545.946294426]: Succesfully connected to 192.168.1.20:2112
[INFO] [1562836545.959231]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1562836546.003055043]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1562836546.003992314]: Waiting 5 seconds for device to connect.
[ INFO] [1562836546.004712598]: Succesfully connected to 192.168.1.10:2112
[INFO] [1562836546.047537]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1562836546.062074051]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1562836546.088674187]: Using fixed control period: 0.050000000
[ INFO] [1562836546.102351210]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.102847933]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.165158547]: Using fixed control period: 0.050000000
[ INFO] [1562836546.165541820]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.165786710]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.179424120]: Using fixed control period: 0.010000000
[ INFO] [1562836546.201063978]: Using fixed control period: 0.050000000
[ INFO] [1562836546.201425065]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.201700812]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.310978798]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1562836546.311299732]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1562836546.311544830]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ WARN] [1562836546.542469330]: No limits found for right_wheel_joint
[ WARN] [1562836546.543635339]: No limits found for left_wheel_joint
[INFO] [1562836546.653819]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1562836546.655601]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1562836546.657002]: Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[INFO] [1562836546.671080]: Loading controller: mobile_base_controller
[ INFO] [1562836546.679591447]: Controller state will be published at 50Hz.
[ INFO] [1562836546.681652574]: Wheel separation will be multiplied by 1.
[ INFO] [1562836546.682677084]: Left wheel radius will be multiplied by 1.
[ INFO] [1562836546.682709134]: Right wheel radius will be multiplied by 1.
[ INFO] [1562836546.683230025]: Velocity rolling window size of 10.
[ INFO] [1562836546.685403788]: Velocity commands will be considered old if they are older than 0.05s.
[ INFO] [1562836546.686312455]: Allow mutiple cmd_vel publishers is enabled
[ INFO] [1562836546.687436633]: Base frame_id set to base_footprint
[ INFO] [1562836546.688066782]: Odometry frame_id set to odom
[ INFO] [1562836546.688741612]: Publishing to tf is enabled
[mobile_base/initialization-17] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pem-robot/.ros/log/73c31b08-a3bc-11e9-ad01-2087563168c2/mobile_base-initialization-17*.log
[ INFO] [1562836546.710399381]: Odometry params : wheel separation 0.75, left wheel radius 0.076, right wheel radius 0.076
[ INFO] [1562836546.714744488]: Adding left wheel with joint name: left_wheel_joint and right wheel with joint name: right_wheel_joint
[ WARN] [1562836546.727189280]: updateConfig() called on a dynamic_reconfigure::Server that provides its own mutex. This can lead to deadlocks if updateConfig() is called during an update. Providing a mutex to the constructor is highly recommended in this case. Please forward this message to the node author.
[ INFO] [1562836546.731060851]: Dynamic Reconfigure:
DynamicParams:
    Odometry parameters:
        left wheel radius: 1
        right wheel radius: 1
        wheel separation: 1
    Publication parameters:
        Publish executed velocity command: 0
        Publication rate: 50
        Publish frame odom on tf: 1
[INFO] [1562836546.740530]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_state_controller, mobile_base_controller
[INFO] [1562836546.770559]: Started controllers: joint_state_controller, mobile_base_controller
EMCY: 81#0000000000000000
EMCY: 82#0000000000000000
[INFO] [1562836547.169613]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1562836547.171515]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1562836547.173639]: Loading controller: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso
[INFO] [1562836547.228936]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso
[INFO] [1562836547.378802]: Started controllers: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_torso
[torso/robot_initialization-14] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pem-robot/.ros/log/73c31b08-a3bc-11e9-ad01-2087563168c2/torso-robot_initialization-14*.log
EMCY: 8A#0000000000000000
EMCY: 85#0000000000000000
EMCY: 86#0000000000000000
EMCY: 83#0000000000000000
EMCY: 84#0000000000000000
EMCY: 87#0000000000000000
EMCY: 88#0000000000000000
EMCY: 8C#0000000000000000
[INFO] [1562836549.858769]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1562836549.860460]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1562836549.862553]: Loading controller: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh
[rh_arm/robot_initialization-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pem-robot/.ros/log/73c31b08-a3bc-11e9-ad01-2087563168c2/rh_arm-robot_initialization-5*.log
[INFO] [1562836549.927448]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh
[INFO] [1562836550.327735]: Started controllers: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh
EMCY: 8A#0000000000000000
EMCY: 85#0000000000000000
EMCY: 86#0000000000000000
EMCY: 83#0000000000000000
EMCY: 84#0000000000000000
[INFO] [1562836555.220237]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1562836555.221943]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1562836555.223388]: Loading controller: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh
[INFO] [1562836555.291805]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh
[lh_arm/robot_initialization-9] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pem-robot/.ros/log/73c31b08-a3bc-11e9-ad01-2087563168c2/lh_arm-robot_initialization-9*.log
[INFO] [1562836555.591805]: Started controllers: pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh
EMCY: 8C#502323DF00000000
[ERROR] [1562836598.652061211]: Node has emergency error
```

This is my drivers.yaml:

```
name: arm

defaults:
  eds_pkg: pem_arm_rh
  eds_file: "config/Schunk_0_63.dcf"

nodes:
  rh_arm_0_joint:
    id: 10
  rh_arm_1_joint:
    id: 5
  rh_arm_2_joint:
    id: 6
  rh_arm_3_joint:
    id: 3
  rh_arm_4_joint:
    id: 4
  rh_arm_5_joint:
    id: 7
  rh_arm_6_joint:
    id: 8
  rh_arm_finger_left_joint:
    id: 12
    pos_to_device: "pos*2000000.0"
    pos_from_device: "obj6064/2000000.0"
    vel_to_device: "vel*2000000.0"
    vel_from_device: "obj606C/2000000.0"
```

This is my controllers.yaml:

```
# Settings for ros_control control loop
hardware_control_loop:
   loop_hz: 125

# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
   joints:
     - rh_arm_0_joint
     - rh_arm_1_joint
     - rh_arm_2_joint
     - rh_arm_3_joint
     - rh_arm_4_joint
     - rh_arm_5_joint
     - rh_arm_6_joint
     - rh_arm_finger_left_joint

# Publish all joint states ----------------------------------
joint_state_controller:
   type:         joint_state_controller/JointStateController
   publish_rate: 50

# Joint Trajectory Controller - position based -------------------------------
# For detailed explanations of parameter see http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller
pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_rh:
   type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
   publish_rate: 50
   joints:
     - rh_arm_0_joint
     - rh_arm_1_joint
     - rh_arm_2_joint
     - rh_arm_3_joint
     - rh_arm_4_joint
     - rh_arm_5_joint
     - rh_arm_6_joint
     - rh_arm_finger_left_joint
   required_drive_mode: 7
```

Strangely this issue only occurs **sometimes**. After restarting the robot several times it works again as expected, but it is very annoying.
Do you have any advise on how to solve this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328248/emergency-error-of-schunk-pg70/) by [verena](https://answers.ros.org/users/37639/verena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From diagnostics:

```
key: "errors"
value: "2350#df"
```

`23xx` errors are related to the current ("Current, device output side").
This protects your devices from overheating.
Perhaps your payload is too high or the drives are somehow broken.
Better ask Schunk directly.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [k5519995](https://answers.ros.org/users/40605/k5519995/) on 2019-07-12**:
I get the error in `"gripper/driver: motor"`.  That is

```
level: 0
name: "gripper/driver: motor"
message: ' '
hardware_id: "none"
values: 
    - 
       key: "error_register"
       value: "32"
    - 
       key: "errors"
       value: ' '
```

How can I know from where I am getting this error while this one has no error code. ?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2019-07-12**:
Not all errors get signaled via EMCY. In addtion, `ros_canopen` resets 0x1003 ("errors") on init and recover.